# Send inputs from an Android App to Google Documents Spreadsheet

Tags: java, android, spreadsheet, documents

my friend and I are currently making a simple Weather chance calculator  android app for a summer project. The app currently works by asking the user for some inputs using some EditTexts (formatted in decimal numbers) that are then put into a simple formula and then a result is spit out.

What I want to do is take the user inputs and transfer them to a public Google Docs spreadsheet, so that EditText1 goes to cell A1, EditText2 goes to cell A2, ect.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks,

Comment: How'd it work in the end?

Comment: Worked pretty well! I ended up migrating to a backend of my own with a real API, but this solution is fine for temporary arrangements.

Comment: Which solution are you using now?

Comment: Implemented my own backend in flask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve same with out google forms, use app scripts follow the below tutorials

How To Use Google Sheet As DataBase For Android App Part - 2 | Post data Sheet from Android App
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QZZrMlUiH2M

Comment: Thanks for the update! Google Scripts are relatively new, so I am going to change the accepted answer to your's as it seems to be a more robust and futureproof method.

Answer (score 1):

Found a decent answer here, the solution is pretty well explained: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GyuJ2GtpZd0